# Why does this Objective C code crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1? (Uses block syntax and dicts)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, objective-c-blocks

```
//Section 1 (declarations)    

NSString *foo;
NSString *bar;

NSDictionary *foobar =
@{
    @"bar":^{return @"foo";}
 };
typedef NSString *(^barfoo)();
```

Given the above declarations, why does only the very last line of the following Objective-C code generate

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1

```
//Section 2 (crashes)

foo = foobar[@"bar"];             //no error, foo == @"foo"
bar = foobar[@"foo"];             //no error, bar == nil
foo = ((barfoo)foobar[@"bar"])(); //no error, foo == @"foo"
bar = ((barfoo)foobar[@"foo"])(); //EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1
NSLog(@"%@%@",foo,bar);           // never runs!
```

I should note that in a try/catch, the catch does not catch anything; no exception gets thrown. Changing `foobar`'s contents to `@{@"bar":^NSString*{return @"foo";}` does not help.

I should also note that the following code *does work* and *does not error*:

```
//Alternate Section 2 (does not crash)    

barfoo foobard = foobar[@"foo"];
barfoo barfood = foobar[@"bar"];
barfood ? foo = barfood() : nil;
foobard ? bar = foobard() : nil;
NSLog(@"%@%@",foo,bar);          // Returns foo(null)
```

Note: the code is executing on iOS 9.2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am confused as to why *you* are confused.

Since `foobar[@"foo"]` is `nil` (as your comments correctly show) you cannot treat it as a block and call it. That is why `((barfoo)foobar["@foo"])()` crashes.

The second code segment simply does not call anything when it detects that the object you got form the dictionary is `nil` therefore it does nothing with the return of `foobar[@"foo"]`

Regarding the `try catch` - it does not throw an error, it *crashes*. That is something different. Something the program cannot recover from. Something that you as the developer have to make sure does not happen. It is your job to make sure that the block you are trying to invoke is actually non-`nil`.

Comment: OK I was looking at it wrong. Thanks. Lets not go into *why* I was looking at it wrong :D

Comment: @CommaToast okay, happens ;)

Comment: Well actually I think I can elaborate. I was looking at the *assignment* of the result of the code block running, not the fact that you can't run a nil block. I guess I figured that the runtime would just treat it like running a method or function which has no lines of code in it. I suppose that's something which could be fixed with an update to the compiler, since it should either fix that on the fly to do that, or it should warn you. (Maybe it does warn, and I just had that type of warning turned off, if that's the case, then my bad.)

Comment: @CommaToast okay, glad we cleared that up - in fact the runtime does not do that. That is why whenever you expect a block to be passed you generally have to wrap the call in `if (block) { block(); }`

Comment: Or use the question mark syntax like `block ? (block()) : (foo = bar);` Because :?

Comment: @CommaToast of course, you can certainly simply use the ternary operator to make things shorter, yes.